# Javascript cryptography libraries

Tags: javascript, cryptography

How effective is it to implement HMAC using JavaScript libraries like crypto-js ?

In the example provided in crypto-js website 
[ https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2 ] it is mentioned

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
```

If the secret key is mentioned in the java script file itself ,any one can check the view source and know about the secret key.

Is my understanding correct ?

Also , please let me know when such crypto javascript libraries need to be used in web applications ?

Comment: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx What are you trying to protect?

Comment: @SLaks I am working on a sample web application , and would like to make my AJAX calls secure without using HTTPS/SSL. and I came across this JS library.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to add security without HTTPS; the attacker can simply add a keylogger to your JS code.

Comment: @SLaks so when should these JS libraries be used ? just curious.

Comment: In Node.js (server-side code), and in occasional scenarios when your site is already served entirely over HTTPS.  You need a threat model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Here is the points:

### Firstly

The work can be used server side, with node.js. So, no security issue about the secret key

### Secondly

Client side, the security issue exists, but the HMAC-X functions are used to **sign messages**, so the normal workflow is to use the user secret passphrase to sign a message and then, send it on the network (the signed message, not the secret). The secret should be deleted when the job is done.

So the user can access to the secret by debugging the code, but it's his so... no really security issue in facts.

Comment: Yes, but without HTTPS, an attacker can steal the password.

Comment: @Rémi Becheras , will it be possible for you to share some link or info about the "Secondly" approach you mentioned in the answer . thanks.